# Safari doesn't seem to know the difference between border-top and border-bottom

Tags: html, css, safari

I am trying to make it so that when it is in focus the bottom border of the text area is colored and when it isn't selected its grey, the left, right, and top are supposed to not be visible, just blank. So on Chrome and other browsers this(check the jsfiddle) works, but if you run it on safari it doesn't seem to know the difference between the border-top and border-bottom attributes. I think it is just something stupid, I just can't see what it is.

```css
input[type=text] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
    outline: none;
}
input[type=text]:focus {
    width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  //This made me think that since the left, right, and top weren't designated it was filling those in automatically, but if you uncomment the next few lines you will see that left and right work, but if I set top to 0px it also sets the bottom to 0px. And I have no idea why safari is doing this
  //border-left: 0px;
  //border-right: 0px;
  //border-top: 0px;
  border-bottom: solid 2px transparent;
  -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #DEAFDB 0%, #EFB9AD 100%);
  -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #DEAFDB 0%, #EFB9AD 100%);
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #DEAFDB 0%, #EFB9AD 100%);
  border-image-slice: 1;
```

```html
<form>

<label for="test">test</label>
<input type="text" id="test" name="test">
</form>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#
```

the js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/atb2tL53/#&togetherjs=Hr31iDIE0Q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by doing the following:

1. Remove the `border-bottom: solid 2px transparent` because it is unnecessary: you've already defined that it's 2px and solid, and the `border-image` will overwrite the color.
2. Comment back in the `border-top`, `border-left`, and `border-right`.
3. Move the to after the `border-image` and `border-image-slice`.

I believe in Safari the `border-image` stuff was overwriting the `border-top`.

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/atb2tL53/4/

Here's a tidier version: https://jsfiddle.net/atb2tL53/7/

Answer (score 0):

So, not sure how you got yourself into this state-- seems like there's a lot of errant rules running around.  Also, `//` is not a valid CSS comment.  There's no line comments in CSS (although preprocessors often have them, like Sass).  Comments in css are done by wrapping the commented section in `/*` to start and `*/` to end.

On to the answer, I just fiddled with what you've got to get it working in Safari-- not sure how much of what you had in there was testing code when it came to the border, so if you want to add it back do so slowly and carefully, with CSS's "last rule applies" policy in mind.

```css
input[type=text] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
    outline: none;
}
input[type=text]:focus {
    width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-bottom: solid 2px blue;
}
```

```html
<form>

<label for="test">test</label>
<input type="text" id="test" name="test">
</form>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#
```